# How to remove all items in RecyclerView Adapter with Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to delete one item if user swipe, and delete all items in `RecyclerView` if user click deleteAll button, I try to access each viewholder an add a Animation but I don't now how, I add Animation in creation because the adapter give me each view holder in `onBindViewHolder`, this is my adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<String> stringList;
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> stringList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.stringList = stringList;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    holder.bind(stringList.get(position));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stringList.size();
}



public void dismiss(int adapterPosition) {
            stringList.remove(adapterPosition);
            this.notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
    }

public void removeItem(int position) {
    this.stringList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() - position);
}




class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView textView;
    String data;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void bind(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        textView.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        stringList.remove(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}}
```

my `RecyclerView` and adapter in main activity and how i handle delete all, but the problem is how I can add Animation

```
  adapter = new MyAdapter(this,myList);
    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SwipeHelper(adapter);
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = myList.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
                adapter.removeItem(i);
            }
            //recyclerView.removeItemDecoration();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which animation do you actaully what to do? Is it the swipe animation similar to what gmail has when you want to delete a mail with your phone?

Comment: yes I want when user click delete all all items slide out of recycler view

Comment: The proper way of doing animations in `RecyclerView` is through `ItemAnimator`. Don't put animations in adapter because it's not adapter's responsibility to animator layout changes. check this video :  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_Tt7q77qwyKRgytF1RzRx8&index=6). For more details , check this repository : [repo](https://github.com/vicky7230/Paprika)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by deleting a single item at a time by simulating a swipe animation on this item, and post a delay before deleting the next item, and so on to the way down to the last item of the `RecyclerView`

**Step No.1:**

In your activity that holds the clear all button and the `RecyclerView` instance: Create a method of single item delete

```
private void deleteItem(View rowView, final int position) {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(),
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    anim.setDuration(300);
    rowView.startAnimation(anim);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (myDataSource.size() == 0) {
                addEmptyView(); // adding empty view instead of the RecyclerView
                return;
            }
            myDataSource.remove(position); //Remove the current content from the array
            myRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh list
        }

    }, anim.getDuration());
}
```

**Step No.2:**

Create the method that will delete all `RecyclerView` list items >> call it in your button click callback.

```
boolean mStopHandler = false;

private void deleteAllItems() {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            if (myDataSource.size() == 0) {
                mStopHandler = true;
            }
            
            if (!mStopHandler) {
                View v = myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView;
                deleteItem(v, 0);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }
            
            handler.postDelayed(this, 250);
        }
    };
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

Also it's important to handle configuration change in manifest, activity section, as if the configuration changes while clearing your recycler view list, an exception will be raised

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
</activity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html

> This class defines the animations that take place on items as changes
>   are made to the adapter. Subclasses of ItemAnimator can be used to
>   implement custom animations for actions on ViewHolder items.

You can refer any tutorials on writing custom `ItemAnimator`: [1](https://hackmd.io/s/r1IEQ-jAl), [2](http://blog.trsquarelab.com/2015/12/creating-custom-animation-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Threads and delay in each loops to remove/restore items one by one. Here's how I have implemented:

**MainActivity.java**

```
clearItemsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final List<LineItem> lineItemsCopy = new ArrayList<>(lineItems);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.removeItem(0);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.items_cleared_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(getString(R.string.label_undo), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                                        final int finalI = i;
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.restoreItem(lineItemsCopy.get(finalI), 0);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(500);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    }).setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
    //Only remove & restore functions are shown    
    public void removeItem(int position) {
        lineItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(LineItem item, int position) {
        lineItems.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
```